# Join on two tables having single columns with no matching condition

Tags: sql

I have codes table with following data

```
_________
dbo.Codes
_________
AXV
VHT
VTY
```

and email table with the folowing data

```
_________
dbo.email
_________
x@gmail.com
y@gmail.com
z@gmail.com
```

and I am looking forward to join these two tables horizontally with the following output.

```
__________
dbo.output
__________ 
AXV    x@gmail.com
VHT    y@gmail.com
VTY    z@gmail.com
```

Is there any way possible to get the desired output?

Edit #1
Both the tables contain unique codes and unique email addresses

Comment: Are both tables always in the exact same order?
Else it is not possible, because there is no Relationship.

Comment: please check the edit i have made

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are unique. The above question remains. You need some 'link'.

For example: If you have a fourth entry in both tables, can you be sure they belong to each other?

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL etc.) is this?

Comment: It's more like that i need to assign a code to every email address in any way possible, one way i thought for the same is by joining on ROW NUMBERS but that is not somehow possible in the tool I am using. I am looking for some other way around.

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is SQLServer, try:

```
; with 
c as (select codes, row_number() over (order by codes) r from codes),
e as (select email, row_number() over (order by email) r from email)
select codes, email
from c join e on c.r = e.r
order by c.r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
select c.Codes , e.email
from CodesTable c, emailTable e
where c.rownum = e.rownum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email, code
FROM 
(SELECT email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY email) AS RowNum FROM email) AS T1
OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY code) AS RowNum FROM codes) AS T2
ON T2.RowNum = T1.RowNum
ORDER BY COALESCE(T1.RowNum, T2.RowNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table

> create table test(
>       code varchar(32),
>       email varchar(32)
>       unique(code),
>       unique(email)
>   );

Execute the result of this sql

> select 'insert into test (code, email ) values (''' +  code +  ''', ''' + email + ''');' from test1 , test2

All sqls won't be successfully executed but table will be fulled in order
When you select test table you will get what you want