# In SQL Server, How to join two table having different column name and different data row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have two tables `T1` & `T2`. I want resulting output table as O1 with help of a SQL query

```
T1 {SName} 
T2 {VName} 

O1 {SName, VName}
```

Comment: How do you want the two tables joined. Are you trying to making the table longer (concatenating results) or make the table wider (joining rows). Please add a simple exampe with 2 or 3 rows in each table and what you would want the output table to look like.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733860/join-on-two-tables-having-single-columns-with-no-matching-condition

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways of doing it.one easy way is:

```
select T1.SName,T2.VName from T1,T2;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a cross join of the two tables to include all combinations of rows in T1 and T2. Try this:

```
Select SName, VName From T1 Inner Join T2 On 1=1
```

The number of rows you will get is the product of the number of rows in T1 and T2 each.

Comment: SQL-Server has `CROSS JOIN`. No need for the `INNER JOIN ... ON 1=1` construction.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i am right, you can use cross join.
if you have two tables `Players` and `GameScores` then
`SELECT* INTO O1 FROM GameScores CROSS JOIN Players` will return all records where each row from the first table is combined with each row from the second table. Which also mean CROSS JOIN returns the Cartesian product of the sets of rows from the joined tables.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago!)

Comment: but u see @marc_s http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056673/creating-a-new-table-from-two-existing-tables-with-every-combination-possibility also they did the , thing

Answer (score 0):

Select record from T1 and T2 based on filtering criteria  and then insert record in table O1 , use below query to create table O1 and inserting those records.

```
 INSERT INTO O1(SNAME, VNAME) 
    SELECT(T1.SNAME, T2.VNAME)
    From T1 Inner Join T2 On 1=1 //i.e WHERE T1.id=T2.T1_id
```

use **WHERE** to filter records

Answer (score 0):

if you're not joining on anything and want a table of all possible combinations:

```
select SName, VName
into O1
from T1 cross join T2
```

if you have a column to join on:

```
select SName, VName
into O1
from T1 inner join T2 on T1.col = T2.col
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the above result as

```
T1 {SName} 
T2 {VName} 
O1 {SName, VName}



 (SELECT * FROM T1,T2) as O1;
```

will definitely work if both the table have single value if not then you can select the 
Particular column like T1.SName,T2.VName